# Disable TextArea ala Facebook when clicked outside TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, events

I have a textArea and a Button - I want the Button to disappear when the user clicks anywhere in the app window EXCEPT the "Send" button

```
<mx:Button x="306" y="168" label="Button" id="btn" click="Alert.show('Button clicked')"/>
<mx:TextArea x="138" y="146" focusOut="btn.visible=false" focusIn="btn.visible=true"/>
```

I tried calling btn.visible=false when TextArea loses focus (using focusOut event) - if I click anywhere in the app it works, but it also works when I click the Button - the TextArea focusOut event is processed first and the click for the button later - can someone please help out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I previously said use call later, but on testing it doesn't work, sorry for wasting anyone's time. Instead you need to use the focus manager something like this: I tested this and it seems solid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.managers.FocusManager; //pull in the manager

    private function onFocusOut(event:FocusEvent):void{
            if(getFocus() != null){ //in case focus goes outside the flash player
                if(getFocus().name == "btn"){ //the focus went to the item with the ID "btn"
                    return; //do nothing, let the click handler work
                }else{ //any other item gets focus
                    btn.visible=false;  //disappear 
                }
            }
        }

    private function clickHandler():void{ // made it it's own function so do more than just alert
        Alert.show('Button clicked');
        btn.visible=false;
    }
]]>
</mx:Script>

    <mx:Button x="306" y="168" label="Button" id="btn" click="clickHandler();"/>
    <mx:TextArea x="138" y="146" focusOut="onFocusOut(event)" focusIn="btn.visible=true"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I was typing it off the top of my head, when I looked into it I needed to add the function inside the callLater. The updated example should work.

Comment: hmm, nopes invertedSpear, sorry this doesn't work either.. I am updating the code below...

Comment: I took your code and played with it. I personally don't know why the call later doesn't work, but I'm still pretty new to flex. This new code has been tested and runs fine. Hope it works for you so you can get a move on with your project :-)

Answer (score 0):

were u trying to override the default focusOut handler? That doesn't work...

```
private function setBtnNotVisible():void
{
    btn.visible=false;
}
override protected function focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
{
    callLater(setBtnNotVisible);
}
```

Neither does writing my own event handler...

```
private function setBtnNotVisible():void
{
    btn.visible=false;
}
private function focusOutHandler2(event:FocusEvent):void
{
    callLater(setBtnNotVisible);
}
```

--------------------- Full Code ------------------

##### Try clicking INSIDE the textArea and then on the button, I cannot catch the Alert

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.Alert;

    private function onFocusOut(event:FocusEvent):void{
            callLater(
                function ():void{
                    btn.visible=false;
               }
            )
        }
]]>
</mx:Script>

    <mx:Button x="306" y="168" label="Button" id="btn" click="Alert.show('Button clicked')"/>
    <mx:TextArea x="138" y="146" focusOut="onFocusOut(event)" focusIn="btn.visible=true"/>

</mx:Application>
```